# A bounded sequence cannot be divergent. True or false

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

"A bounded sequence cannot be divergent." Is this statement true?
As far as I know a bounded sequence can either be convergent or finitely oscillating, it cannot be divergent since it cannot diverge to infinity being a bounded sequence. Contrapositively, can I say an unbounded sequence can either be divergent or infinitely oscillating?

Comment: "Divergent" means "not convergent".

Comment: Recall that a sequence is said to be divergent if it is not convergent. Hence if it oscillates, it is considered to be divergent.

Comment: @MisterRiemann I use another terminology, that is  1) convergent: $a_n \to L\in \mathbb{R}$, 2) divergent: $a_n \to\infty$ or $a_n \to-\infty$ 3) Not convergent nor divergent otherwise.

Comment: A bounded sequence which is neither finally oscillating nor convergent is $1/1,1/2,2/2,1/3,2/3,3/3,1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4,1/5,2/5,\dots$.

Comment: @HansEngler I'm used to a different terminology that is "divergent" means that $a_n$ diverges to$ \infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: That is a nonstandard terminology then. [[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSequence.html)] [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)]

Comment: @MisterRiemann I've seen that some authors make the distinction for the case 2 denoting that as ["properly divergent"](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/properly-divergent-sequences). I think that this kind of distinction can be very useful.

Comment: @gimusi I've never seen such a convention. In any case, even the attached link classifies any sequence that does not converge is as a divergent sequence.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Yes now I'm convinced that my proposal is not well accepted by the comunity :)

Comment: @jiren : This question depends entirely on your definition of _divergent_.  It is not an interesting question, or a question to "wonder" about: Just plug your example/counter-example into your definition and you are done. You have not provided any definition, and so your question cannot be adequately answered. [PS: I would personally never use the term _diverge_ or  _divergent_ unless I give it in context in a phrase such as "$e^n$ diverges to infinity as $n\rightarrow\infty$." ]

Comment: @Michael I agree with you but from all the other comments here it seems that only one terminology should be adopted? Personally, I prefer to distiguish the three cases as indicate here above.

Answer (score 8):

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  (-1)^n$$

Comment: What should that prove?

Comment: this sequence is bounded but divergent

Comment: Yes sorry I was referring to a difefrent terminology! Of course your example is fine

Comment: I am confused about the asker being "jiren" and also seemingly "gimusi" at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

State that your sequence is unbounded. Suppose it has no upper bound (the same logic is to be applied if it has no lower bound).

So:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R, \exists n \in \mathbb N, u_n > x$$

Work a bit with this, and the definition of limit:

$$ \exists a \in \mathbb R,  \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N, n > n_0 \implies |u_n - a | < \epsilon $$

The definition of limits tells you that for every $\epsilon$, there is a rank $n_0$ such that $(u_n)_n$ is bounded for $n>n_0$. Since there is a finite number of terms $u_n$ for $0 \le n\le n_0$, the sequece is also bounded for $n \le n_0$.

This is a contradiction with the undounded hypothesis, and you can then conclude that the "convergent" hypothesys is wrong.

Comment: I think you've mixed up the pieces - this is a proof that a convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: @T.Bongers So, a non bounded sequence is non convergent. Which I though was the question, but it may have been a bit more precise than that, with "divergent or infinitely oscillating" not being equivalent to "non convergent", as shown by Michael Hoppe comment

Comment: Just from the title, though, the question is asking for an example of a bounded sequence which is divergent or a proof that a bounded sequence is convergent.

Comment: @T.Bongers my bad, I was answering the last sentence: "Contrapositively, can I say an unbounded sequence can either be divergent or infinitely oscillating?". I think I mixed up quite a few things indeed. I'll let the answer anyway, unless OP states that it doesn't help him at all. Thanks for pointing it out